# VB - Append to array?

Tags: arrays, vba, vbscript

this is probably a super simple question. But I have this Array that I need to strip useless parts from. But I still want it in an array.

So, the array looks like this when it comes in:

```
ArrValues(0) "Firstname=FIRSTNAME"
ArrValues(1) "Lastname=LASTNAME"
ArrValues(2) "Username=USERNAME"
ArrValues(3) "Displayname=DISPLAYNAME"
```

Then I send this array through this code snippet:

```
For Each s In arrValues
    s = Split(s, "=")
    s = s(1)
Next
```

This strips the strings so I get only `FIRSTNAME` and so on.
But, I want to send each cleaned string into an array again. How do I do that?

Comment: Your idea is to take the string right after the = sign? If so, I'd suggest you to use the MID function.

Comment: @Tiago - Why use MID? What's wrong with using the Split function?

Comment: @Joel Goodwin There's nothing wrong at all using Split. But the split function relays in the fact that all values are declared as Variants, because they'll be re dimensioned i.e. a variant with one value "Firstname=FIRSTNAME" will become a array with two values, (Firstname, FIRSTNAME). Using MID function, we'll avoid it. As stated in my post, I'm not a performance expert (does exist a VBA performance expert?) but I believe that's better to avoid this redim whenever is possible. Still, Split does the desired work too.

Comment: @Tiago - That is a decent point. Split forces you into Variant territory which I have never really liked. Perhaps if this function were being called many times it might be the subject of some performance testing but I've relied on Split for fast access to String pieces for some time, regardless of the horror of Variants. I tend to copy them back onto strings if I need to remember them.

Comment: I agree @Joel Goodwin regarding Variants. Most of the VBA questions we have here at SO about VBA are pointed to small applications, then using Split or Mid wouldn't really care, as long as the code works. Still, I think that's a good practice to guide our users to good practices, like variables properly typed and avoid variants as much as possible.

Comment: I've never understood the hate variants get. In general, variants are one of VBA's most useful features, especially when VBA is combined with Excel. In this specific case, it would hard to see how avoiding them would improve on e.g. @Helen's answer. Something like `arr(i) = Split(arr(i), "=")(1)` is practically self-documenting.

Comment: Variants aren't hated (they're great, actually). Variants _wrongly_ used, are hated, though.

Comment: I actually do hate variants, I'm a bit of mental typist myself. I prefer hard typing on function calls and variables to block unexpected scenarios. Java and C# suffer from similar issues sometimes when something is banded around as an "Object" type, although VBA embraces variants in a bigger way. But on a small scale like this, I've learned to let go of my Variant-hating racist prejudice and love a little more.

Comment: Using the Mid function is easier to use when the value might contain an "=", as in:  Base64enc=c3VyZQ==

Comment: @Tiago, @Joel - As with any kind of dynamic typing, VBA variants are at their most useful when writing scripting code, or rapidly prototyping something. They get less useful as a system gets large or performance becomes important. But aren't most VBA programs the former? I can see some variant-hate being justified if you're a 90s-era VB programmer building huge systems, but that hate seems to have seeped down into VBA conventional wisdom in a bit of a cargo-cult way. Even in the Excel community, which is downright weird given their utility in Excel specifically.

Comment: @jtolle I believe that's a good question to discuss about. I've created this topic to see further oppinions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488314/using-variant-variables-in-vba-should-it-be-avoided-or-not

Comment: @Tiago, it is a great question, and I just posted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you have all strings with an '=' sign, this code should work... using MID function. I'm not an performance expert, but I believe that a MID function would have a better performance than the SPLIT (since split will redim each value).

Still, Helen's code might work as well. Just sharing this code to show my MID approach :)

```
Sub MidArray()

    Dim ArrValues(3) As Variant
    Dim vValue As Variant
    Dim iCount As Integer

    ArrValues(0) = "Firstname=FIRSTNAME"
    ArrValues(1) = "Lastname=LASTNAME"
    ArrValues(2) = "Username=USERNAME"
    ArrValues(3) = "Displayname=DISPLAYNAME"

    For iCount = LBound(ArrValues) To UBound(ArrValues)

        ArrValues(iCount) = Mid(ArrValues(iCount), InStr(ArrValues(iCount), "=") + 1)

    Next iCount

End Sub
```

Comment: BTW, your code doesn't write back to the array - that's what the question is actually about.

Comment: Ups... Thanks, Helen! Code Fix'd.

Comment: Thanks! This was actually be very same thing as I figured myself :) With slight differences. But I do think Helen's suggestion was the one I was looking for in the first place though. But I think I'll set this one as the answer anyway. Mainly because she's got a higher reputation ;)

Answer (score 7):

To write back to the array, you need to use the `ArrValues(index) = new_value` notation. So, you need to use a regular `For` loop instead of `For Each`, and access the array elements by their indexes. Here's how you can do this:

```vb
For i = LBound(ArrValues) To UBound(ArrValues)
 s = ArrValues(i)
 s = Split(s, "=")
 ArrValues(i) = s(1)
Next
```